# When is it safe to assume a double is zero

Tags: double, rounding, zero

I'm programming this symbolic math program, and I'm questioning the way I detect a zero constant, for example to check if it should return a sum or just a single object.

Right now I'm checking `if (-Double.MIN_NORMAL <= constantPart.evaluate() && constantPart.evaluate() <= Double.MIN_NORMAL)`, although I'm not sure this margin is sufficient.

Is it bad to rely on the gradual underflow to produce a denormalized value less than `Double.MIN_NORMAL`? What should the error margin be otherwise.
Would for example `2 * Double.MIN_NORMAL` suffice?

I could obviously do some testing, but I feel like that wouldn't quite inform me of what's happening inside.

Is there a way to determine a sufficient margin for any specific case?

Comment: What's your goal? Precise symbolic math? Then you can't use float operations that don't give a precise result. Most don't do that in a predictable way. Maybe all you need is `x == 0.0`.

Comment: The goal is not necessarily to be exact, most interesting operations aren't exact. `Math` precision is good enough, what I'm wondering is if my check will ever return true in cases like where you count down from 2 to 0. Also I read something about the fact that when a value denormalizes it impacts performance, would that occur before my test returns true?